# How to know what query is running to fetch data in website and how to extract it Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch Day Average Temperature which is available on website https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/pk/karachi/OPKC/date/2017-1-3. But I am not getting any value or if I just copy paste data it show "No data recorded" instead of tables on that website. What I am doing wrong?
I am using following code...

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36',
    }
r = requests.get('https://www.wunderground.com/',headers=headers)
res = requests.get("https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/pk/karachi/OPKC/date/2017-1-3")
import urllib.request
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
for table in tables:
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    print( tabulate(df[0], headers='keys', tablefmt='psql') )
print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: Right click anywhere on the page, check Inspect Element, go to the Networks tab, check the requests being made and the responses that are being received. Additionally, also check out Selenium.

Comment: I didn't see a 'table' tag when I did this: for tag in soup.find_all(True): print(tag.name)

Comment: You should do some research on web scraping dynamic content using python, because the tables on your target site are being generated.

Comment: Yes man I am trying to learn code. Actually I am new to coding and learning python 3. But to get data from a website you need to know HTML, SQL json etc. and other things as well. For that I have no idea at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked the response with requests and found no table tags in r.content. Instead of reading from the page, consider using its API with below method.

By passing the params into get method to get a json response. Then just get what you want by iterating through each objects of the json response.

```
import requests
import csv

base_url = "https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/24.90138817/67.15000153/observations/historical.json?"

data = {
  "apiKey": "6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e",
  "startDate": "20170103",
  "endDate": "20170103",
  "units": "e"
}

r = requests.get(base_url, params=data)
d = r.json()

headers = ['timestamp', 'temp', 'precip/hr', 'windspeed']
with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(headers)
  for item in d['observations']:
    writer.writerow([item['expire_time_gmt'], item['temp'],item['precip_hrly'], item['wspd']])
f.close()
```

Prints below

```
timestamp,temp,preciptation/hr,windspeed
1483392300,63,,7
1483394100,61,,3
1483395900,61,,3
1483397700,59,,7
1483399500,59,,6
1483401300,59,,5
1483403100,57,,7
1483404900,57,,5
1483406700,57,,5
1483408500,57,,9
1483413900,55,,7
1483415700,55,,7
1483417500,55,,6
1483419300,55,,3
1483421100,57,,3
1483422900,61,,3
1483424700,64,,5
1483426500,66,,7
1483428300,66,,5
1483430100,72,,5
1483431900,73,,0
1483433700,75,,2
```

Comment: Hi,
And good day to you...
Thanks man for the answer and guiding me in a new thing. Appreciated!
Have a blessed day :)

Comment: Please send some time to upvote if the answer is what you are looking for :)

Comment: When I UPVOTE, system says that
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."
Sorry!!!